# Laravel routes file cannot find Controllers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a very simple routes.php file:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'TracksController@index');
```

And a simple TracksController.php file located at App\Http\Controllers:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Track as Track;

class TracksController extends Controller
{
    function index(){

        $tracks = Track::latest->get();
        return view('tracks')->with(compact('tracks'));

    }

}
```

But whenever I try to access that route I get this error:

```
ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Class App\Http\Controllers\TracksController does not exist
```

I have no idea what else I can do. I have:

- Run composer dumpautoload
- Run php artisan clear-compiled
- Checked permissions on the storage/* folders
- Forcing the namespace and/or fullpath of the TracksController in the routes file

But nothing seems to be working.

I even checked the vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php file generated by composer and I cannot find the TracksController file there.

Any clues?

Comment: check your function `function index(){}` should be `public` function index(){}`

Comment: make the function public, and remove everything inside of it and put this `dd('test');` and remove the `use App\Track as Track;` and if you see the word test on your page then the answer is obvious

Comment: It may have been a typo in your question, but the command should be `composer dump-autoload`, with a hyphen. If it wasn't a typo, try that and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: composer allows for `composer dump-autoload` or `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: @AndrewNolan Huh. Just tested that and it works. I did not know that. Thank you for the information.

Comment: You taught me something did the same in return. #winning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with your `$tracks = Track::latest->get();`

change to `$tracks = Track::latest()->get();` and you should be set.

Comment: If no visibility is defined, PHP defaults visibility to public. While it looks better to specify it, leaving it off does not change how the code works.

Comment: I have always been use to stating public, protected, private that I didn't try it on my own first. Thanks for the knowledge, patricus

Comment: No problem. I always specify the visibility, as well.

Comment: For your updated answer, while you're correct that `latest()` is missing the parentheses to make it a method call, you still need the `get()`. `latest()` just adds the `orderBy` to the query, it does not actually execute the query, so you still need `get()` to execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux, file names and paths are case sensitive. Assuming you haven't changed the autoloading in the default `composer.json` file, PHP is expecting the file to be located at `app\Http\Controllers\TracksController.php`. In your question, you specified it is located at `App\...`.

Assuming this wasn't a typo in the question, you either need to rename your `App` directory back to `app`, or you need to update your `composer.json` file to let it know to autoload from the `App` directory, and not the `app` directory:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "App/"
    }
},
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using resource controllers, you must declare the use of the controller in the routes/web.php file, as following:

```
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\UsersController;
...
Route::resource('users', UsersController::class);
```

This works here using Laravel 8.

Answer (score -1):

What I found that you must declare the use of the controller in the routes/web.php file and routes/api.php,in laravel 8 and higher ,as following:
`

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route
use App\Http\Controllers\Controllername
Route::get    ('/', [    Controllername::class,'index'    ])
`
for each controller
for more help see the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPRV2ctCMGI

Comment: This is a 7 year old question that is explicitly tagged for Laravel version 5.